# Tomcat 7.0.40 returning the same session id after invalidation

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

On Tomcat, I have the below lines of code

```
session.invalidate();
session = request.getSession(true);
```

but the new session is having the same sessionId as the prior one that was invalidated.
What is causing this behaviour? how can I force tomcat to create the session with new session id.

Upon Debugging I see that even though the session object referenced in request becomes null, there is this requestedSessionId attribute in request and the container is just using that id to create the new session, how can I override that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved with Tomcat version 7.0.72. looking at the change log there are quite a few enhancements and bugs related to sessionID generation being addressed between 7.0.40 and 7.0.72. So one of them probably addressed this.